# dismiss to home from another view controller swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller, dismiss

I have multiple view controllers in my app. I am wondering, is there a way to segue to home from the third view but still dismiss the third view? Preferably without a navigation controller. But please tell me if I need one. thanks for the help.

Comment: Why don't you wanna use a navigation controller. It is a clean way to achieve the desired behaviour. Also, the question is very hard to answer because you don't explain the context.

Comment: Use an unwind segue

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your custom Segue, and then apply it to your Segue between the two views.

Here is one example (Current view will replace previous one):

```
class ReplaceSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let sourceController: UIViewController = self.sourceViewController
        let destinationController: UIViewController = self.destinationViewController
        let navigationController = sourceController.navigationController!
        let controllerStack = NSMutableArray(array: navigationController.viewControllers)

        controllerStack.replaceObjectAtIndex(controllerStack.indexOfObject(sourceController), withObject:destinationController)

        navigationController.setViewControllers(controllerStack as NSArray as! [UIViewController], animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Try the below functions in your code.
In your home view controller, input a kind of welcoming/receiving segue function:

```
@IBAction func unwindToVC(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = segue.source as?       *Name of third view controller* {
        //in here you can now access any information you 
        //want to retrieve from the third view controller
      }
 }

//In your third viewController put the following:
//make sure you assign cancelSegue to a button or whatever

func cancelSegue() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToMain", sender: self)
}
```

Then in storyboard on the third view controller you refer to, right click drag from the yellow circle at the top of the view controller into the orange square "exit" and then it will bring up an option called unwindToVC and click it. Make sure it is identified (as you can see in cancelSegue, mine was called segueToMain as the identifier.

Now when you are in the third view controller, you should be able to press the assigned button and it will perform the segue

This worked for me, hope it helps